# ASP.NET MVC View looking by Model value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

For some reason the view engine is searching for the view based on the string value I'm passing as the view Model.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

This is a simplified version of my action method.  This is displaying the error condition where a tag isn't found and instead or returning the default View I return a different error page view "TagNotFound":

```
    public ActionResult Tagged()
    {
        string tag = "SomeValue";

        return View("TagNotFound", tag);
    }
```

The view `TagNotFound.cshtml` exists but the search is wrong.  This is the error I get:

```
The view 'TagNotFound' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Tag/SomeValue.cshtml
~/Views/Tag/SomeValue.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/SomeValue.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/SomeValue.vbhtml
```

Instead of using a class to call the correct overload as suggested I cast the string as an object.

```
return View("TagNotFound", (object)tag);
```

Comment: Did you customize any of the framework components in ASp.NET MVC?  Do you also have any custom routes?

Comment: No customizations.  David below explained why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because [the overload for the `View()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310(v=vs.118).aspx) expects a string to be the name of the view.

Because of this, a string by itself can't be a view model.  Instead, you might consider either putting the string in the `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.tag = "SomeValue";
return View();
```

Or creating a view model with just that one value:

```
public class TagViewModel
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}

// elsewhere...

return View(new TagViewModel { Tag = "SomeValue" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Per MSDN, this is what you are returning:

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
 string viewName,
 string masterName
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743(v=vs.118).aspx